# How to store ArrayList data when screen is rotated?

Tags: android, arraylist, serialization, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I tried storing array list data by using serializable and parcelable but in both case when I get the data using getParcelable and getSerializable. I am getting error due to @Deprecated or Type Mismatch.

```
       val time1ArrayTennis: ArrayList<TimeArr>
       time1ArrayTennis = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable("time1") as ArrayList<*>

    //TimeArr is data class
      data class TimeArr(
          val time1 : Int
           ) : Serializable
```

Can someone please help how to in a simple way I can save and restore data when screen rotates?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what is `TimeArr` in your code snippet. Probably you're getting an error, because it doesn't implement `Parcelable` interface. So you have at least 2 options:

1. Implement `Parcelable` interface for your `TimeArr` class. And then use `outState.putParcelableArrayList("time1", time1ArrayTennis)` to store your array in `Actiivty.onSaveInstanceState()` method. And then get it from `Bundle` after Activity's recreation in `onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle)`
2. Save this data in [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

Your ViewModel class:

```
    class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

        val time1ArrayTennis: ArrayList<TimeArr>

        .....

    }
```

Your Activity class:

```
    class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

        .........

        private fun someFunWhereYouWorkWithData() {
            val data = viewModel.time1ArrayTennis
            // TODO: work with data
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping.
Can you provide a good reference for implementing Parcelable for Arraylist?

Comment: You need to implement Parcelable for your TimeArr. Just check out the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable